# I want to create a menu with anchor tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

As I said in the title, I want to create a menu with anchor tags, but I've been looking for something similar on Youtube and other sites, and I haven't found it.

In my idea, I want to do, is a submenu similar to the menu on the right side of vue.js documentation or vuetify, below I'll show you a picture of it. (I am also using vuetify)

Example of what I want -> (https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAiAZ.png)

I do not know what to call this or where to find an example (mainly due to my limited experience in this new world), so if anyone could help me, I'd be really thankful :)

I tried to see some repositories and Youtube videos about it. I think that this is called a menu or submenu, but I can't figure it out...

Best regards and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a component inside vuetify that's do what you want. its name is `v-navigation-drawer`. 
here is a demonstartion code:

```
<v-navigation-drawer
v-model="drawer"
app
>
<v-list dense>
  <v-list-item v-for="item in items" :key="item.title">
    <v-list-item-content>
      <v-list-item-title>
        {{ item.title }}
      </v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
  </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```

and options here:

```
export default {
data () {
return {
  drawer: false,
  items: [
    { title: 'Home' },
    { title: 'About' },
    { title: 'Contact' }
  ]
}
}
}
```

hope this helps.